# Get to nested dictionary in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm struggling to get to a nested dictionary in a list.

```
L = [{'color':'yellow','fruit':'banana'},{'firstname':'Jack','lastname':'Black'}]
```

I can get the individual dictionaries with the following code.

```
for a in L:
   print (a)

{'color': 'yellow', 'fruit': 'banana'}
{'lastname': 'Black', 'firstname': 'Jack'}
```

But now I only want the dictionary with lastname/firstname.

**After the tips posted to my question, I came up with the following code.**

```
def getPhotosFromAlbum(albumName):
    availablePhotos = []
    availableAlbums = getAlbumList()
    print("Looking in album %s" %albumName)
    for album in availableAlbums:
        if albumName == album['AlbumName']:
            #print ("found photos for album: ", albumName['KeyList'])
            for photoRefKey in album['KeyList']:
                print(getPhotoPath(photoRefKey))
                availablePhotos.append(getPhotoPath(photoRefKey))
    return availablePhotos
```

The idea behind this function is that I can parse the list in a HTML template file to display the photos. So my follow up question is: is this code ok or is there a more Python like approach to achieve the same result.

Darrell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
only_last_and_first = [d for d in L if 'firstname' in d and 'lastname' in d]
```

Now you have a list of dictionaries that have those two keys.

Demo:

```
>>> L = [{'color':'yellow','fruit':'banana'},{'firstname':'Jack','lastname':'Black'}]
>>> [d for d in L if 'firstname' in d and 'lastname' in d]
[{'lastname': 'Black', 'firstname': 'Jack'}]
```

If you only wanted the *first* such a dictionary, use `next()` and a generator expression:

```
first = next((d for d in L if 'firstname' in d and 'lastname' in d), None)
```

Here `first` will be set to either the first dictionary with the two keys, or `None` if there is no such dictionary.

If such syntax is a little daunting, here is a version with a `for` loop instead:

```
first = None
for d in L:
    if 'firstname' in d and 'lastname' in d:
        first = d
        break
```

Comment: But how do I get the information out?
`L = [{'color':'yellow','fruit':'banana'},     {'firstname':'Jack','lastname':'Black'}]
only_last_and_first = [d for d in L if 'firstname' in d and 'lastname' in d]
for i in only_last_and_first:
    for key, value in i.items():
        print(value['firstname'])`

Comment: @DeChinees: You are looking too much. `i` is a dictionary, you do not need to loop over `i.items()`. Just `print(i['firstname'])` is enough.

Comment: @DeChinees: If you wanted to loop over all items in `i`, then print those items directly: `for key, value in i.items(): print(key, value)`

Answer (score 1):

I build on Martijn's answer to propose a solution:

- returning a print of items, just like in your example (and not a list)
- checking that keys are exactly `'lastname'` and `'firstname'` (not just contain)

script uses an helper to check very simply if one list is sublist of another

```
L = [{'color':'yellow','fruit':'banana'},{'firstname':'Jack','lastname':'Black'}]

def contains_sublist(lst, sublst):
    for k in sublst:
        if k not in lst:
            return False
    return True

for di in L:
    if len(di.keys()) == 2 and contains_sublist(di.keys(),
                                                       ['firstname','lastname']):
        print di
```

returns

```
>>> 
{'lastname': 'Black', 'firstname': 'Jack'}
```

////////// EDIT -- thanks Martijn

You can use `.viewkeys()` for increased efficiency

```
L = [{'color':'yellow','fruit':'banana'},{'firstname':'Jack','lastname':'Black'}]

for di in L:
    if len(di) == 2 and di.viewkeys() & {'firstname','lastname'}:
        print di
```

this one checks if intersection between both sets is non empty `di.viewkeys() & {'firstname','lastname'}`

Comment: Take a look at [dictionary view objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects); you can do this much more efficiently using set operations.

Comment: `len(di)` is more efficient; no need to create a whole list of keys when all you need to do is ask the dictionary for the length.